# GridView Gallery with images uploaded from XAMPP server

Tags: java, android, gridview, xampp, gallery

I have to do a GridView Gallery in android xml which is using images from XAMPP server.

I have the code for uploading from a file:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

public static int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
                R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,
                R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12,
                R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14};
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter (Context applicationContext)
{
    context = applicationContext;
}
```

Comment: I din't get it, you already have the images or do u want to get it from the XAMPP server?

Comment: yes i want to get images from xampp server not like the example(from the drawable file)